# Network access behaviour problem

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I have Debian Wheezy 64 bit installed on my PC. The problem is that in some situations I can only ping `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` and don't have access to outside world. And in other cases I can ping everywhere but `localhost`.

Here is `/etc/hosts`

=======================================

```
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    127.0.0.1   my-pc

    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

=======================================

And here is `/etc/network/interfaces`

=======================================

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # The primary network interface
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.5.65
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.5.0
        broadcast 192.168.5.255
        gateway 192.168.5.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.5.1 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4

    #iface eth0 inet static
    #   address 192.168.5.65
    #   netmask 255.255.255.0
    #   gateway 192.168.5.1
    #auto eth0

    #allow-hotplug eth0
    #iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

=======================================

And here is `/run/network/ifstate`

=======================================

```
    lo=lo
    eth0=eth0
```

=======================================

After a restart, `ping localhost` fails and `ping [rest of the world]` works. but after any restart in networking service, only `ping localhost` works.

Comment: Change your second line to either `127.0.1.1 my-pc` or `<permanent ip> my-pc`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

File /etc/nsswitch.conf must be present and contain the below line:

```
    hosts: dns files
```

In my case it was solved. Don't know why, but it was empty!